# Why does my Javascript method return NaN when two number types are calculated?

Tags: javascript, parsing, methods, nan, typeof

I am learning Javascript, and I am coming across a couple of hiccups. This is my first post here, please help me understand:

1. Why does a number (ex: 2024), subtracted by my javascript object property: 'this.birthYear' (ex: 1995, clearly a number) return Not a Number (NaN)? Could this possibly be a parsing error to my browser's console?
2. And, if this is my error, what would I need to change in my code to make 2024 - 1995 = 29?

Here is my code:

```
const penguin = {
    firstName: 'Zachary',
    birthYear: 1995,
    job: 'Developer',
    friends: ['Michael', 'Joe', 'Evan'],
    hasDriversLicense: true,
    
    // methods
    calcAge: function () {
        this.age = 2024 - this.birthyear;
        return this.age;
    },

    getSummary: function () {
        this.hasDriversLicense ? this.getSummary = 'a' : this.getSummary = 'no';
        return this.getSummary;
    }
};

penguin.calcAge();
penguin.getSummary();

console.log(penguin.age); // why NaN ???
console.log(penguin.getSummary);

// summary

console.log(`${penguin.firstName} is a ${penguin.age} year-old ${penguin.job}, and he has ${penguin.getSummary} Driver's License.`);
```

[Refer to screenshot for my output example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJgzl.png)

Thank you in advance.

I have tried logging to my browser console `console.log(penguin.age)`, which outputs NaN (But, if hard-coding a 1995 number, I get my expected result: 29).

Comment: You have a typo -> `this.birthyear` should be `this.birthYear`. `2024 - undefined` is `NaN`. As an aside: Typescript can help with errors like this. Javascript is a very dangerous language to use without Typescript.

Comment: @AndyRay   simply add `"use strict";`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Comment: @MisterJojo Runtime errors and compile time errors are importantly different in the level of danger they prevent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the spelling of this.birthyear within your calcAge function, you want it to be this.birthYear.

Comment: Oh Dear Lord, I need to double-check my spelling in the future. Lol. Thank you!